# Can't change horizon color: "can't edit driven number value, see graph editor for the drive setup"

Tags: world

I am trying to change my background color for rendering. I tried changing `horizon color` in `World` (circled), but received an error message that I don't understand.

> can't edit driven number value, see graph editor for the drive setup

[image]

Why is this? How may I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purple border indicates that there is a Driver present for that value. A Driver is a way of programatically controlling a value - similar to keyframing. When a value is being Driven you cannot manually change it. Move the mouse to over the field and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to remove it (or right-click for the menu which also lets you add/remove drivers). You probably pressed <kbd>D</kbd> at some point without realising whilst hovering over the field and this would have added the driver.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! I must've pressed D some point like you said.